# How to make Vim's global command :g/ work on per occurrence basis

Tags: vim

Typically Vim's global command :g// works on per line basis. Is it possible to make it work on per occurrence basis as there could be more than one occurrence on a line.

Comment: Answering this question requires knowledge about vim scripting. AFAIK, SU is not about programming -- while the answer requires programming skills...

Comment: @Don: Even if this didn't require scripting up a solution (because the functionality isn't built in), this would still be the right place for it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: What operation do you need to do on every occurrence? Why do you need an operator which works on line if you're not tied to lines?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you could use something like :rubydo, which will run some ruby scriptlet per line of code.  Combining that with gsub in ruby should get you the ability to do just about anything per occurrence of a match.  Of course, you will need to do it with ruby code, which may not give you access to everything that you might need without hassle (register appending would be annoying for instance)

```
:[range]rubyd[o] {cmd}  Evaluate Ruby command {cmd} for each line in the
                        [range], with $_ being set to the text of each line in
                        turn, without a trailing <EOL>.  Setting $_ will change
                        the text, but note that it is not possible to add or
                        delete lines using this command.
                        The default for [range] is the whole file: "1,$".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
command! -bang -nargs=1 -range OGlobal 
    \ <line1>,<line2>call s:Global("<bang>", <f-args>)

function! s:Global(bang, param) range
  let inverse = a:bang == '!'

  " obtain the separator character
  let sep = a:param[0]
  " obtain all fields in the initial command
  let fields = split(a:param, sep)

  " todo: handle inverse
  let l = a:firstline
  while 1
    let l = search(fields[0], 'W')
    if l == -1 || l > a:lastline 
      break 
    endif
    exe fields[1]
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Which you can use as `:global`, except that the command name is different (and that the bang option as not been implemented yet)